# "Failed to connect to database" --> Unable to connect to Azure PostgreSQL DB from Keycloak(AKS)

Tags: keycloak, azure-aks, azure-postgresql

While deploying **keycloak** in **Azure Kubernetes Service** using [Codecentric Helm Chart](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak), it is unable to connect to **Azure PostgreSQL Database**.

After pulling the repository in my local machine, made below mentioned changes in the [statefulset.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codecentric/helm-charts/master/charts/keycloak/templates/statefulset.yaml) file: -

```
env:
  - name: DB_VENDOR
    value: postgres
  - name: JDBC_PARAMS
    value: "true"
  - name: DB_ADDR
    value: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlDbhost | quote }}
  - name: DB_PORT
    value: {{ .Values.postgresql.service.port | quote  }}
  - name: DB_DATABASE
    value: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase | quote }}
  - name: DB_USER
    value: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername | quote }}
  - name: DB_PASSWORD
    value: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlPassword | quote }}
  - name: JDBC_PARAMS
    value: "ssl=false"
```

and provide below mentioned values in [values.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codecentric/helm-charts/master/charts/keycloak/values.yaml) file

```
postgresql:
  # If `true`, the Postgresql dependency is enabled
  enabled: false
  # PostgreSQL DB Host to Connect
  postgresqlDbhost: blabladb.postgres.database.azure.com
  # PostgreSQL User to create
  postgresqlUsername: someuser@keyclockdb
  # PostgreSQL Password for the new user
  postgresqlPassword: !*blabla*!
  # PostgreSQL Database to create
  postgresqlDatabase: blabladb
  # Postgressqlport
  service:
    port: 5432
```

I have disable the **Enforce SSL Connection** in Azure for testing purposes.
Then, after deploying the helm chart from the local(local PC) repository, getting the below mentioned **error**: -

[Warning Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT8l4.png)

[Error Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJeNz.png)

Please advise on what would be the cause for this issue.

Comment: Any news on that one ? I'm facing pretty much the same problem.